# How does public transportation work in SimCIty?

Tags: simcity-2013

I'm wondering if someone could shed some light and advice on how to manage public transport and traffic in general in SimCity. I always end up with traffic chaos even though I try to have bus stops coverage everywhere and street cars on main streets. This results in a lot of unnecessary problems because various utility and safety vehicles are always stuck in traffic.

How do I use public transportation best to improve traffic conditions?

Comment: @AeroCross Huh? Already in the game. Just asking for advice from others as I know there are a lot of smart players out there who has probable figured out some details I haven't :)

Comment: Aerocross' comment was a tongue-in-cheek reference to the launch problems.

Comment: To answer your question, all I know is that intersections cause all buses to pick a random direction.

Comment: @RavenDreamer So the buses and all might become smarter after a while once they get their servers fixed and stuff improved?

Comment: Not a server issue. The online part of the simulation is restricted to regional stuff, which means intra-city bus behavior won't change. They still might update the AI later on, though.

Comment: I have noticed that once you get a population around 250k that traffic on even avenues reduces to a crawl, I think it might have something to do with the number of intersections within the city (vehicles waiting at lights) but haven't built up a new city of similar size to test yet

Comment: I played around with this a lot last night in a high density city and it seems to be that while public transport alleviates the effect of traffic, you're much better off by designing your road layout in a way that reduces the number of intersections and allows traffic to get to the busy parts of the city with the fewest number of stops possible. All of my testing was done in sandbox using streetcar avenues with 3x bus and 3x street car services, I haven't done much testing with rail yet but I suspect this would further reduce the traffic on the main road into the city.

Comment: http://www.simcity.com/en_US/blog/article/simcity-update-6-streetcars

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the current version of the game that the developers have acknowledged. In a [recent blog](http://www.simcity.com/en_US/blog/article/simcity-update-8), Simcity lead designer Stone Librande acknowledged the following concerning traffic and agents:

> "we are seeing the emergence of many cities that test our systems in unique ways."
>
> "We are currently testing a patch internally and hope to have it out to you soon,"

So in other words, don't demolish your city just yet. Wait for the traffic patch and see if the improved logic helps your issue.

**EDIT :** This patch is now out, labeled patch 1.7

Comment: Yep, have kind of paused my SimCity playing while waiting on a patch for this mess. kind of ruins the experience to say the least :p

Comment: On the upshot, I have been having a lot of fun creating some unusual city layouts trying to force the AI into the optimal path.